# Using GUID to remove member from AD Group

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting, active-directory

When it comes to managing the users in Active Directory, PowerShell scripts always come to the rescue. However, it is possible to do same tasks in multiple way. I am working on a project that uses GUID as a unique identifier to manage the users in the relevant Active Directory groups. Both groups & group members have their unique GUIDS. So, is it possible if I have two GUID values one of group & another of various users, I can remove the membership of the user from that group?

Here's what I tried:

```
$GroupGUID = 'a3d65150-1739-4cc7-80d2-7b97c76b0aff'

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupGUID  |
    Where-Object {$_.ObjectGUID -eq '8a3fab53-4c8b-483d-89f0-e26de236a627'} |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-ADGroupMember $GroupGUID $_ -Confirm:$false }
```

However, there should be a simple way of doing it without using for loop I guess.

Comment: What happens when you run the code you posted?

Comment: It will remove the member from the AD Group the code is working fine I was just wondering if there is any simpler version available or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to remove a member from a group given both GUID's?

```
$GroupGUID = 'a3d65150-1739-4cc7-80d2-7b97c76b0aff'
$MemberGUID = '290a89dc-9886-4ab3-ac2a-6071234563d5'
Get-ADGroup $GroupGUID | Remove-ADGroupMember -members $MemberGUID -confirm:$false
```